# My shortcode does not call the function

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to make a shortcode with two parameters `$number_posts` and `$category_name`.

The shortcode is calling another function named `bg_make_post_grid` that uses those parameters as variables.

I added `wp_die()` to the function to see if it was being called, and it does not kill WordPress so I don't think the function is being called.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Add Shortcode
add_shortcode( 'bg_recent_post_grid', 'bg_recent_post_grid_shortcode' );
function bg_recent_post_grid_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'category_name' => 'uncategorized',
            'number_posts' => '1',
        ), $atts );

    return bg_make_post_grid ( $atts['number_posts'], $atts['category_name'] );

}


function bg_make_post_grid ( $number_posts, $category_name ) {

    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => $number_posts,
        'category' => $category_name,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
    );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    wp_die();

}
```

Comment: Does `bg_make_post_grid()` return a value or echo something?

Comment: In the future it will return do more and return something, but for now I just wanted to see if it was being called by adding wp_die() and it turned out it does not.

Comment: Did you try `echo do_shortcode('[bg_recent_post_grid]');` or `echo bg_recent_post_grid_shortcode([]);` ? And where did you add the code? Is it in `functions.php` or a plugin you wrote?

Comment: Code was in a plugin. The problem I had was related to the plugin somehow, I just had to deactivate and reactivate under a different name and it started working. Should I delete the question now? Not sure what is best practice in that situation, since the fix was not code related.

Comment: You can write an answer (and accept it), but I think it's up to you..

Answer (score -1):

Please replace the old code with below code it will show you that it's working

```
add_shortcode( 'bg_recent_post_grid', 'bg_recent_post_grid_shortcode' );
function bg_recent_post_grid_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'category_name' => 'uncategorized',
            'number_posts' => '1',
        ), $atts );

    return bg_make_post_grid ( $atts['number_posts'], $atts['category_name'] );

}


function bg_make_post_grid ( $number_posts, $category_name ) {

    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => $number_posts,
        'category' => $category_name,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
    );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    print_r( $recent_posts); die;

} 
 echo do_shortcode('[bg_recent_post_grid]');
```

Comment: This has the same result. It doesn't do anything. Also calling bg_make_post_grid outside of the shortcode does not prove the shortcode can call the function. P.S. that was not me who down voted you.

Comment: > Above code is working for me so i told you.